# Angular 4 plugin for eclipse

Tags: angular

I have started a project using angular 4. I want to create angular project in eclipse.

Please suggest me any free plugin to create angular 4 project in eclipse.

I have tried [Angular IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide) which is not a free plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be considered off-topic here on SO.... ;)

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started ?

Comment: @Angelo yea, but OP wants to create "Angular 4" project, not "Angular 2" project. Currently (2017-06-28) the only tool, which supports "Angular 4" is "Angular IDE".

Comment: Angular2 Eclipse should support Angular4. I think that Angular IDE provides  a feature to convert Angular2 project to Angular4 project. Is this feature that you wish to have? Otherwise please tell me which features are missing to develop Angular4 with Angular2 Eclipse.

Comment: There is no difference between angular2 and angular4 except a few brealing changes in the framework. This has nothing to do with IDE support so the plugin works for angular4 too. Angulat IDE cannot convert angular2 to 4 as there is nothing to convert. It only gives possibility to upgrade angular-cli version of tje project (Rc to final if I remember correctly)

Comment: Thank you all for valuable suggestions. I have completed the project using Visual Studio Code IDE. It is free and open-source. It has good suppport for angular4.

Answer (score 9):

First off I don't understand why folks keep suggesting AngularIDE when he SPECIFICALLY says that he wants a free product lol.

Second you should honestly just look at the angular2-eclipse project: https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started it will work with any version of Angular2 or beyond (which as other comments have suggested are all the same). All this plugin provides is a good typescript editor for eclipse plus some integration with the angular cli.

Answer (score -5):

Go to this site and just drag install button to your Eclipse IDE.
It is automatically go to that market place.
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide

Comment: He said he does not want angular IDE !